# What's written on the book?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, password

I have a riddle for you guys:

> *Of the four I am the oldest, of the five I am the lowest. On my back I have a temple and at it's feet what you need to find a woman. Look at her sister pointing at her. On the book she holds you'll find the solution.*

**Starting point:**

<kbd>64</kbd><kbd>33</kbd><kbd>244</kbd><kbd>189</kbd>

So...

#### What's written on the sister's book?

---

**HINT 1**

> The starting point is a **location**.

**HINT 2**

> You must do a little lookup.

**HINT 3**

> You'll understand now: `64.33.244.189`

**HINT 4**

> Ok, there you are: https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/64.33.244.189

**HINT 5**

> The starting point is **Mount Rushmore** (Was it that hard?).

**HINT 6**

> George Washington

**HINT 7**

> Of the four [presidents] I am the oldest, of the five [?] I am the lowest. **Quick note**: I'm talking about the same person here (Already given in the previous hint).

**HINT 8**

> Oh, you still can't figure it out? [Let me help you, then](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=presidents%20currently%20printed%20on%20dollar%20bills).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, take two after having my first, non-hidden (rightfully) removed ...

The answer is:

> 'IV JUILLET 1776 = XIV JUILLET 1789'

How I got here:

> Despite misinterpreting the first part, the thing with a woman holding a book brought to mind the Statue of Liberty. I know that she has a "sister" in Paris that faces her, so figured this had to be part of the answer.
>
> After reading other's progress and the answers about the first parts of the riddle, and then re-reading the riddle more carefully, I see that I answered with the phrase from the wrong book, from the wrong sister.
>
> Instead of the US version, the riddle asks for what's on the book of the sister that points at her. The US gifted the "sister" statue back to the French with both the July 4, 1776 date as well as adding the French independence date, aka Bastille Day and an equals sign, presumably to say that they are of equivalent importance.

Comment: Please write in your answer (the 1st spoiler) only the _exact_ content written on the sister's book. Then you can add your explanation in the 2nd spoiler. I'll mark your answer as the correct one, but the bounty will be given only to the answer that explains the _whole_ riddle (all of its parts, even though most of it is already in the hints I gave).

Answer (score 4):

Of the four I am the oldest:

> The hints indicate Mount Rushmore, based on the four numbers being an IP address.  Of the four heads on the mountain, George Washington is the oldest.

of the five I am the lowest:

> Perhaps something with heads on denominations?  But there are 6 denominations of bills (100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1) and 4 commonly used coins (.25, .10, .05, .01).  Perhaps also Washington, or Lincoln.  EDIT:  Lowest of the "5" unit denominations: nickel: Thomas Jefferson

On my back I have a temple and at it's feet what you need to find a woman.

> Perhaps a US bill: The $10 has the US Treasury on the back, fairly temple-like, with "US Treasury" at its feet...
>  Alternatively the "temple" could be the Lincoln Memorial.

Look at her sister pointing at her.

On the book she holds you'll find the solution.

> Lady Liberty holds a book, with the date: JULY IV MDCCLXXVI (July 4th, 1776)  EDIT: Alternative "woman holding a book": Hellen Keller State Quarter?

Comment: +1 for the right answer in the 1st spoiler. But that's still not the password. You'll have to do a little more research to find the _true_ password. You're _almost_ right on the second spoiler, though. But it's the lowest of the **5** (yes, that's the number) that I want.

Comment: Adding to that, the following clues remain unexplained: _"On my back I have a temple and at it's feet what you need to find a woman."_ and _"Look at her sister pointing at her. "_

Comment: Now you're getting colder...

Answer (score 3):

Not much left to do here. Maybe we can get it together:

Ok, lets summarize the starting hints:

> Interpreting the starting point as an IP Adress $64.33.244.189$ and doing a DNS lookup we get **cpe-64-33-244-189.mt-rushmore.net** which leads us to
>
>  $$Mount\ Rushmore$$

Of the four I am the oldest

> Mount rushmore has four **president** heads from which **George Washington** is the oldest

of the five I am the lowest.

> There are currently $7$ different US-Dollar bills in circulation, from which $5$ are **presidents**:
>  1 Dollar  : **George Washington**  (<- **the lowest**!)
>  2 Dollar  : Thomas Jefferson
>  5 Dollar  : Abraham Lincoln
>  10 Dollar : Alexander Hamilton (no president)
>  20 Dollar : Andrew Jackson
>  50 Dollar : Ulysses S. Grant
>  100 Dollar : Benjamin Franklin (no president)

On my back I have a temple

> the back of the **one dollar bill** shows a **pyramid**, some sort of a temple

and at it's feet what you need to find a woman.

> on the base of the pyramid there is a roman number **MDCCLXXVI** (1776, the year of the Declaration of Independence) which we use to find a woman having something to do with this:
>  $$The\ statue\ of\ liberty$$
>  has this number inscribed in the book she is holding.

Look at her sister pointing at her.

> The statue of liberty has a small sister located in paris pointing at her

On the book she holds you'll find...

> the book of the small sister, not the big one from Ellis Island!

... the solution.

> **IV JUILLET 1776 = XIV JUILLET 1789**  *(as pointed out already by Zymurge)*

Comment: Congratulations for explaining the whole riddle! +50.